# What is the difference between Html.Label and Html.Display?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

What is the difference between `Html.Label` and `Html.Display`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Html.Label()` renders HTML markup `<label />` that can be used for a model entity's attrubute.

For eg,

```
<%= Html.Label("Full Name", Model.FullName) %>
```

would render

```
 <label for="FullName">Full Name </label>
```

`Html.Display()`  on the other hand renders HTML markup for entire entity based on specified templates. For eg. if you have a Person entity with multiple attributes, you define a template with markup as to how to render a Person and `Html.Display()` uses that template to render Person objects across views. Phil Haack has an excellent [post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-tabular-display-template.aspx) on display templates.

Comment: See this post http://forums.asp.net/t/1993021.aspx?Using+Html+Label+html+helper for the new overloads in the newer mvc versions

Answer (score 3):

[Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310185%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Returns an HTML label element and the property name of the property that is represented by the specified expression.

[Display](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310174%28v=VS.98%29.aspx)

Returns HTML markup for each property in the object that is represented by a string expression.

Answer (score 0):

**Html.Display** is more dynamic it generates different HTML markup depending on the data type of the property that is being rendered, and according to whether the property is marked with certain attributes. The method renders markup according to the following rules:

If the property is typed as a primitive type (integer, string, and so on), the method renders a string that represents the property value.

If a property is annotated with a data type attribute, the attribute specifies the markup that is generated for the property. For example, if the property is marked with the EmailAddress attribute, the method generates markup that contains an HTML anchor that is configured with the mailto protocol, as in the following example:

```
<a href='mailto:joe@contoso.com'>joe@contoso.com</a>
```

If the object contains multiple properties, for each property the method generates a string that consists of markup for the property name and for the property value.

**Html.Label** just generates a label tag like Male